# How to call session.set_keys from the CLI?

Tags: session, validator

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#submitting-the-setkeys-transaction

Upto this point in the documentation, it's easy to get a session key from calling rotate keys, however the way to call `set_keys` is not shown. I don't have access to a PolkadotJS apps GUI right now and would like to change my keys for my validator node. How should I build this extrinsic, sign it and send it from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cli, you can use the [polkadot-js api-cli](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/tree/master/packages/api-cli) -

```
$ polkadot-js-api --seed ... --tx tx.session.setKeys 0x....
```

There is also a docker image available with all the `polkadot-js/tools` tools.

Comment: Hello, running `api --seed .. --tx tx.session.setKeys 0x... --ws ws://127.0.0.1:9944` gives me a `Error: You need to specify the command to execute, e.g. query.system.account`. Why is that?

Comment: Also it requires two arguments, what should the second arg be?